# TWA app error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm converting my pwa website to twa and i'm having some troubles.

when I try to sync or build the project i'm getting the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (no error message)

I'm new to android and java, can someone helpme here?

I'm using bubblewrap/cli
my gradle:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder  // ERROR : Cannot resolve symbol 'MarkupBuilder'
 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def twaManifest = [
    applicationId: 'br.com.estudoon.www.twa',
    hostName: 'www.estudoon.com.br',
    launchUrl: '/login', 
    name: 'Estudoon!',
    launcherName: 'OON!', 
    themeColor: '#000000', 
    navigationColor: '#000000', 
    navigationColorDark: '#000000', 
    navigationDividerColor: '#000000', 
    navigationDividerColorDark: '#000000', 
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', 
    enableNotifications: true, 
    shortcuts: [],
    splashScreenFadeOutDuration: 300,
    generatorApp: 'bubblewrap-cli', // Application that generated the Android Project
    fallbackType: 'customtabs',
    enableSiteSettingsShortcut: 'true',
    orientation: 'any',
]

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.estudoon.www.twa"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"

        resValue "string", "appName", twaManifest.name

        resValue "string", "launcherName", twaManifest.launcherName

        def launchUrl = "https://" + twaManifest.hostName + twaManifest.launchUrl
        resValue "string", "launchUrl", launchUrl

        
            resValue "string", "webManifestUrl", 'https://www.estudoon.com.br/manifest.json'
        
        resValue "string", "hostName", twaManifest.hostName
twa#set_up_digital_asset_links_in_an_android_app
        resValue "string", "assetStatements",
                '[{ \\"relation\\": [\\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\\"],' +
                        '\\"target\\": {\\"namespace\\": \\"web\\", \\"site\\": \\"https://' +
                        twaManifest.hostName + '\\"}}]'

        resValue "color", "colorPrimary", twaManifest.themeColor

        resValue "color", "navigationColor", twaManifest.navigationColor

        resValue "color", "navigationColorDark", twaManifest.navigationColorDark

        resValue "color", "navigationDividerColor", twaManifest.navigationDividerColor

        resValue "color", "navigationDividerColorDark", twaManifest.navigationDividerColorDark

        resValue "color", "backgroundColor", twaManifest.backgroundColor

        resValue "string", "providerAuthority", twaManifest.applicationId + '.fileprovider'

        resValue "bool", "enableNotification", twaManifest.enableNotifications.toString()

        twaManifest.shortcuts.eachWithIndex { shortcut, index ->
            resValue "string", "shortcut_name_$index", "$shortcut.name"
            resValue "string", "shortcut_short_name_$index", "$shortcut.short_name"
        }
        resValue "integer", "splashScreenFadeOutDuration", twaManifest.splashScreenFadeOutDuration.toString()

        resValue "string", "generatorApp", twaManifest.generatorApp

        resValue "string", "fallbackType", twaManifest.fallbackType

        resValue "bool", "enableSiteSettingsShortcut", twaManifest.enableSiteSettingsShortcut
        resValue "string", "orientation", twaManifest.orientation
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

task generateShorcutsFile {
    assert twaManifest.shortcuts.size() < 5, "You can have at most 4 shortcuts."
    twaManifest.shortcuts.eachWithIndex { s, i ->
        assert s.name != null, 'Missing `name` in shortcut #' + i
        assert s.short_name != null, 'Missing `short_name` in shortcut #' + i
        assert s.url != null, 'Missing `icon` in shortcut #' + i
        assert s.icon != null, 'Missing `url` in shortcut #' + i
    }

    def shortcutsFile = new File("$projectDir/src/main/res/xml", "shortcuts.xml")

    def xmlWriter = new StringWriter()
    def xmlMarkup = new MarkupBuilder(new IndentPrinter(xmlWriter, "    ", true))

    xmlMarkup
        .'shortcuts'('xmlns:android': 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android') {
            twaManifest.shortcuts.eachWithIndex { s, i ->
                'shortcut'(
                        'android:shortcutId': 'shortcut' + i,
                        'android:enabled': 'true',
                        'android:icon': '@drawable/' + s.icon,
                        'android:shortcutShortLabel': '@string/shortcut_short_name_' + i,
                        'android:shortcutLongLabel': '@string/shortcut_name_' + i) {
                    'intent'(
                            'android:action': 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
                            'android:targetPackage': twaManifest.applicationId,
                            'android:targetClass': twaManifest.applicationId + '.LauncherActivity',
                            'android:data': s.url)
                    'categories'('android:name': 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER')
                }
            }
        }
    shortcutsFile.text = xmlWriter.toString() + '\n'
}

preBuild.dependsOn(generateShorcutsFile)

repositories {
    
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper:2.2.0'
    
}
```

**EDIT:**
I'm getting the same error with any project, even the ones bult in android studio.
Alread reinstalled android studio, XAMPP, java and node.

Answer (score 3):

For Cannot resolve symbol `MarkupBuilder`: Add the `groovy` classpath to your `build.gradle` file in the root folder if you are using `gradle 7`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:3.0.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```